# An issue with muscle fatigue without exertion

Tags: running, health

**Condition:** After a twenty minute workout consisting of walking only (Week 1, Day 3 listed [here](http://sciencebasedrunning.com/2011/08/noakes-on-starting-out-in-running/)) my arm muscles felt unusually fatigued but not sore.

**Question:** What may be the specific problem?

(I suspect this may be due to some dietary (nutritional) deficiency rather than direct physical exertion, since I didn't exercise my arms or upper-body region during the workout.)

---

**Follow-up information and question:** I've faced this problem for some time now. I used to run moderately for some period some time ago, but gave up because my muscles were becoming very fatigued with only modest exertion. - If possible, may an experienced runner provide some feedback on what specifically might be the reason(s)? And how to address this properly?

Comment: Interesting question, I experienced this myself when I began to run, but not to the extent you are experiencing.

Answer (score 1):

The only real answer to this is: see a doctor.  I'm not sure of your age or health, etc. (sounds like you're a college student) - but after a small amount of exercise you should NOT be feeling muscle fatigue.  See a Dr. and get a complete physical, blood work and nutritional assessment.  Don't take this feedback from your body lightly....it's a clear warning sign that something could be wrong.